# iOS safari forces user to click and hold rather than just click to open link inside iframe loaded in modal

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, safari, modal-dialog

Sorry for the long title. The "launch demo modal" button on 'click' opens a modal, which loads an iframe from another domain.  The iframe site is just an image wrapped in an anchor tag with a 'mailto:' href.

the iframe loads via jQuery.

This flow works well on desktop across browsers, and in Android devices (v. 4-6 tested so far).

In iOS, most of the time Chrome loads the mailto link quickly without issue after the user clicks the image.

In Safari, however, the 'tap' is ignored, and only when the user touches and holds the image will safari open a dialog asking the user to "open message".

Has anyone encountered this before?  This is not an issue if loading the iframe directly into a div.  It seems to happen only if loading into a modal, which is hidden at page load time.

You can test on iOS Safari here:

https://valuer-fox-52454.netlify.com/

from researching online I've implemented:

'touch-action: manipulation;' rules to both parent and child pages.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` on the parent page

I've added 'touchstart touchend tap focus' to the 'click' even function.

added an onclick event to the anchor tag and tried using jQuery to link out.

Image mapped a clickable area rather than wrapping the image in an anchor tag.

None of the above affected the iOS safari behavior.

Since I can't find anything specifically related to iOS overriding touch events when in an iframe and/or when loaded into a modal, I figured I'd check here.

Thanks for any assistance.

This is the parent page:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap - Modals (test)</title>
    <link     
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}
    .errors {display: none;}
    .errors h2 {color: red;}
    .coupon {width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
    .coupon iframe {width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: scroll;}
    ol li {margin: 1em 0; line-height: 1.5em;}
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button id="getCoupon" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn- lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
       </p>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h2>Your coupon is below!</h2>
            <div class='coupon' id='mydiv'></div>        
  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getCoupon").on("click", function(){
    var rtxURL = "https://childinmodaltest.herokuapp.com/index.html";

    if (!$('iframe[src="'+ rtxURL +'"]').length > 0) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = rtxURL;
    $(iframe).prop({
      'scrolling': 'no',
      'marginwidth': '0',
      'marginheight': '0',
      'hspace': '0',
      'vspace': '0',
      'frameborder': '0',
      'allowtransparency': 'true'        
    }).css('min-height', '640px');

      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#mydiv').append(iframe);       
      }, 333)
    }   
   });
  });
</script>

<script     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the child page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>child page to be loaded into modal</title>
    <style>
       body {text-align: center;}
       img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="mailto:test@example.com" target="_blank">
    <img src='https://lh3.ggpht.com/vqKa5XeIG6W51gLV-wG_-DfX20FJxGxOw4-AoDQOJAzCqFeoED50-gabK94PFnWbHf8=w300' alt="click me button" />
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, my fix was to use postMessage to communicate from the iframe to the parent page and tell it to redirect on the click event.